# What is the name of this family of functions or curves?

Tags: functions, terminology, exponential-function, curves, programming

Some time ago I was involved at work in making some mechanism to limit and control of an  actuator based on a sensor reading $x$, a lower bound $a$, an upper bound $b$, and an "aggressiveness" constant $k$.

Following the given restraints:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,& x \leq a \\
0 \leq y \leq 1,& a \leq x \leq b \\
0,& x \geq b \\
\end{cases}$$
And, of course, "We should be able to control how fast the effect settles in, how aggressive it is"

My solution was (and still is) this formula:
$$f(x) = {\left(1 - \frac{x - a}{b - a}\right)}^{ k }$$

Example for $k=0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5$:
[image: Examples]

I have programmed it and named it "attenuation_curve", but I don't know if this is its correct name.
What is the name of this family of functions or curves?

Comment: Note $$1-\frac{x-a}{b-a}=\frac{b-x}{b-a}.$$

Comment: The  case when $a=0,b=1$ your function is $(1-x)^k,$ which doesn't have a name. But the others are just linearly scaled and translated versions of this function.

Comment: Thanks! I will modify it in the code when I can :)

Comment: Please see my previous description of the generalization of the superellipse, which I call superconics, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512575/parameterizing-of-squarish-circle/3513796#3513796.