# How do I map a Sphere to a Sphube (a special Superellipsoid)?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

**UPDATE: I realized the formula actually works fine (once I started using  $2/r$ instead of $r$), but the mesh I was working with was not a perfect sphere to begin with, which led to skewed results, as you can see in the last screenshot I posted.**

I'm trying to programmatically create a superellipsoid (specifically a "sphube") in a 3D program (Blender, using geometry nodes) for which I define the flattening.

I want to end up with something resembling these:

[[image: Sphube-like shapes created in Blender by using Catmull-Clark subdivision1]

With the formula I came up with, I'm getting these instead:

[image: Resulting geometry when using the formula described below]

Let me walk you through my process. I start with a sphere with a radius of 1:

[image: A nice little sphere I made by creating a cube and mapping the vertices to a sphere.]

This is the formula I'm using to define the points on the surface of my sphube:

$$\lvert x\rvert^r + \lvert y\rvert^r + \lvert z\rvert^r = 1$$

Where **x**, **y** and **z** are the coordinates of each vertex and **r** is a real positive number (supposedly between 0 and 1) that controls the amount of flattening at the tips and the equator.

My thought process goes like this: I want to find a factor **f** with which to multiply each point's vector from the sphere's origin [0,0,0], so that each point lands on the sphube with the given flattening **r**. This is the formula I end up with:

$$(\lvert x\rvert * f)^r + (\lvert y\rvert * f)^r + (\lvert z\rvert * f)^r = 1$$

I solve for **f** as follows:

$$(\lvert x\rvert^r * f^r) + (\lvert y\rvert^r * f^r) + (\lvert z\rvert^r * f^r) = 1$$

I divide both sides by $f^r$ and switch sides:

$$\frac{1}{f^r} = \lvert x\rvert^r + \lvert y\rvert^r + \lvert z\rvert^r$$

I flip it (or whatever the correct term may be):

$$f^r = \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^r + \lvert y\rvert^r + \lvert z\rvert^r}$$

I take the r-th root:

$$f = \frac{1}{\sqrt[r]{\lvert x\rvert^r + \lvert y\rvert^r + \lvert z\rvert^r}}$$

As mentioned above, I multiply each point of my initial sphere with the computed **f**, but get the star-like results shown above. Since the vectors are obviously going in the wrong direction, I tried dividing, instead, and I get this:

[image: Ooh, we're getting closer...]

This is more like it, but the edges are pointed, instead of rounded, and the centers of the squares are bulged. And no value of r is giving me a perfect cube. So that can't be it either, can it?

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Or, alternatively provide me with a clean formula to map a sphere (or a cube) to a sphube (even if it worked correctly, the method I'm using will result in skewed vertices towards the edges)?

Thanks!

Comment: "$r$ is a real positive number (supposedly between $0$ and $1$)" -- The part in parentheses seems to be where you went wrong. If you set $0<r<1$ the solution of the equation is indeed a spiky object like the ones in the "actual outcome" picture. Try it with $r > 2,$ for example $r = 8.$

Comment: Oh yes, I realized the value I need to be using is not r but 2/r, according to the Wikipedia article. The outcome then becomes the same as when dividing (the last image I attached).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that I can offer an alternative approach that I have used successfully for several years. The idea is to use an extension of the idea of a body of revolution, albeit for revolution about a non-circular closed curve. But first things first.

So, first you need to define the vertical and horizontal curves you will be using. I have developed something I call superconics that will do this very well, and I have described it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512575/parameterizing-of-squarish-circle/3513796#3513796). You will see that it can give you squarish circles, but a great many additional opportunities.

The next step is to develop the *spherical product*. This term does not appear in the mathematical lexicon, but is widely used in computer graphics. Mathematically, it is expressed as

$$
s\left( u,v \right)=h\left( v \right)\otimes g\left( u \right)
$$

where $s\left( u,v \right)$ is the surface composed of vertical curves $h\left( v \right)$ around a closed planiform curve $g\left( u \right)$ and $u$ is the longitude ($0\le u\le2\pi$) and $v$ is the latitude ($\pi/2\le v\le\pi/2$).

Now, apologies here, because I do almost everything in complex variables, So, if you express $h\left( v \right)$ and $g\left( u \right)$ in complex variables, then the components of the spherical product, that is, the matrix $s$, are given by

$$
\begin{align}
  & {{s}_{x}}\left( u,v \right)= & \operatorname{Re}\left\{ h\left( v \right) \right\}\,\operatorname{Re}\left\{ g\left( u \right) \right\} \\ 
 & {{s}_{y}}\left( u,v \right)= & \operatorname{Re}\left\{ h\left( v \right) \right\}\,\operatorname{Im}\left\{ g\left( u \right) \right\} \\ 
 & {{s}_{z}}\left( u,v \right)= & \operatorname{Im}\left\{ h\left( v \right) \right\}  
\end{align}
$$

I suppose that in Cartesian coordinates you would just replace $(\operatorname{Re},\operatorname{Im})$ by $(\cos,\sin)$. I have implemented the spherical product in Matlab with a very minor modification of the *sphere* function, if you are familar with that.

Carrying this a bit further, I've generalized the spherical product to calculate three-dimensional bodies of arbitrary (i.e., non-circular) revolution with essentially any vertical and horizontal profiles. Th animation below shows such a 'body of revolution' with an arbitrary planiform and variable longitude lines

[image: body of revolution]