# Which function looks like this?

Tags: analysis, functions, graphing-functions

I am looking for a function $f(x)$, defined on $[0,1]$ and depending on a parameter $\lambda \in (0,1)$, that approximately has the [attached shape(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JJAo.jpg). One requirement is that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \lambda$. In my sketch I drew the function for different example values of $\lambda$.

Which functions take such a form? What would be their expression?
Or which method could I use to find such a function?

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: If $p(t)$ is any continuous probability density defined in $[0, 1]$ then $1 - \int_{0}^{x}p(t)dt$ will have this shape. You can rescale it to get an integral of $\lambda$

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul, for your answer! This seems like a great idea. I just think that this doesn't work for every continuous probability density in [0,1]. Maybe I should have specified what I mean by "this shape" - namely that f(x) has first a concave part and then a convex part. Which probability density would you take, and how could I "rescale it"? Thanks again

Comment: $p(x)=6(\frac{1}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2)$  is a probability density in 0 to 1,  I have not worked out the function $h(x)$ you will get when you integrate and subtract from 1.. This in turn will have an integral from 0 to 1. Whatever value this integral has you can rescale your $h(x)$ so that the integral from 0 to 1 is $\lambda$.

Comment: Many thanks, Paul. That was very helpful!!

Answer (score -1):

The function you are seeking can be easily described by my previous development of a generalized conics function called superconics, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512575/parameterizing-of-squarish-circle/3513796#3513796). Alternatively, you may get away with using a subset of that which is the superparabola, which can be found in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superparabola). There are figures in both citations that you will see are what you are looking for.